# Nested Cucumber::Ast::Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

How do I create steps to handle this nested cucumber table?

```
  Scenario Outline: Sign Up
    Given I am on the <language> site
    And I am on the home page
    When I follow "<register>"
    And I fill in the following:
      | <fname> | John |
      | <lname> | Doe  |
    And I check "paintball"
    And I fill in the following within Emergency Contact:
      | <ename>   | Jane Doe   |
      | <enumber> | 4161111111 |
    Then I should see "John Doe"
    Examples:
      | language | register  | fname         | lname     | ename | enumber  |
      | en       | Register  | First Name    | Last Name | Name  | Number   |
      | pt       | Registrar | Primeiro Nome | Sobrenome | Nome  | Telefone |
```

The step cucumber asks me to implement is

```
When /^ I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)" $/ do |arg1, arg2, table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

But when I implement it, this forces an arity mismatch error.

```
Your block takes 3 arguments, but the Regexp matched 2 arguments.
(Cucumber::ArityMismatchError)
```

This is expected. Before parsing the features file until the end, cucumber sees the feature has a nested table. Since there is not step definition for this, it asks for one. But after parsing the whole file, Gherkin will translate the table at the end of the feature into individual place holders, thereby nullifying the need for a bested table (or so I think this works).

However, if I implement the previous `When` clause with two arguments going into the scope, I get an ambiguity error that the `--guess` option does not help with.

I have been stuck on this way too long. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The step that cucumber asks you to implement doesn't look right. You have no When like that.

Comment: I was just about to say the exact same thing. I thought it doesn't look right too. I scrapped the language aspect of the feature and still the same issue

Comment: Try starting from a simpler spec, get it working and build it from there.

Comment: I just did that and I realized the problem was because I Cucumber has removed _web_steps.rb_ that babies newbs into BDD. I implemented the `fill_in` clause and the immediate failing Cucumber step seems to be working. I am still developing and if this is a true fix, I will post an answer. Thank you so much for staying with me on this!

Comment: Please read those 2 posts - https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails/blob/master/History.md#v110, http://aslakhellesoy.com/post/11055981222/the-training-wheels-came-off